# How to set the number of lines for an EditText from alertDialog

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I need to set the number of lines to 1 for the EditText from alertDialog. I put input.setLines(1) but it doesn't work. It let me enter more than one line and I see only the last one. So, what is the solution for this?

This is my code :

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
alert.setTitle(data);
        final EditText input = new EditText(this);
        InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
        FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(25);
        input.setFilters(FilterArray);
        input.setLines(1);
        input.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                keyboard.showSoftInput(input, 0);
            }
        }, 200);

        alert.setView(input);
```

Comment: show your code.. how you doin it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it:

```
input.setSingleLine();
```

Comment: I get that this method is undefined for EditText

Comment: It's working for me. and it's supported from API 1? Else this might work: input.setSingleLine(true);